# map integration in iphone application

Tags: iphone, dictionary

i want to integrate maps using map kit in iphone, and i am successful at that, but now the problem which i am facing is

i have 2 locations coordinates, Location1 and Location2, now i want those two points to be shown on map but i want that they appear on the screen both at 1 time, means if they are very far then the zoom level goes to that point and show those two points on the map, if they are near to each other then zoom level shows from that angel (i mean very near).

now i know that using longitude delta and latitude delta i can fix this problem, but i cant find a way to make it dynamic, so that i dont have to hardcode the delta value

Any Help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate;
centerCoordinate.latitude = (location1.latitude + location2.latitude) / 2;
centerCoordinate.longitude = (location1.longitude + location2.longitude) / 2;

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = ABS(location1.latitude - location2.latitude);
span.longitudeDelta = ABS(location1.longitude - location2.longitude);

[mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span)]
          animated:YES];
```